# Need help with generating good and bad effects to magic

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spellcasting, homebrew

First time poster so sorry if this question already came up.

I'm creating a D&D 3.5 campaign where PCs come to a cursed island where magic casting becomes... A bit weird. What I wanna do is every time someone casts a spell, for the spell to have additional effects. For example: a mage throws a fire ball. Behind the (DMs) screen I will throw a D6 (or whatever) to add effects to the spell :

- On a 1 the spell hits the caster
- On a 2 nothing happens
- On a 3 spell hits normally but attracts aggro
- On a 4 spell hits normal
- On a 5 spell has extra boom
- On a 6 nothing happens for 1 turn, the 3 fireballs come flying from the sky

What I need from you good people is more ideas and effects. Some advice would be most cherished.

Comment: Welcome to the stack! I recommend checking out our [tour], it helps understand how this site works. Other confusions can be resolved by looking through the [help] or asking in comments, or in [chat].

Comment: As it stands, your question will likely be closed as an idea generation (or brainstorming) question, which is off-topic on this stack. If you have specific ideas you would like the community to evaluate, based on specific points that worry you (will it break anything major? will it be unfun for players? and so on), you're free to ask about those, and we should be able to give proper feedback on those. [This FAQ](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5758/77044) should give more context on this.

Comment: "Is there a published list of random effects that a spell can have in addition to its normal effects?" is a fine question (and, yes, there is at least one published list). Likewise, "Is this homebrew list of random extra spell effects balanced?" (then include the list) is fine. Edit the question to be either of those, and the stack can help.

Comment: The answers to this very similar question might be interesting for you: [Is there an official rule-set for unstable magic in dd 3-5?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/36268/is-there-an-official-rule-set-for-unstable-magic-in-dd-3-5)