# Madness Rules for 3.5

Tags: dnd-3.5e, eberron, background

So, I am running a game of D&D 3.5 and I have a player character in the group whose backstory includes his mother having gone insane at some point in the past.  As she is a marked heir of her house, money shouldn't be a thing for having her madness removed magically (Eberron Dragonmarked house, Lyrander, essentially a mercantile family with wealth to rival nations) yet the player wishes for her madness to be beyond the ken of most readily available spells.  I was wondering if the Lords of Madness book has any rules on this.  I was thinking of a few things here.

1. her madness is a coping mechanism, something in her past was so horrible that she does not want to confront it.
2. her madness is some sort of unknown curse or ailment.
3. it is the effect of a Daelkyr's direct influence on her (this is my current train of thought).

I don't want it to be as simple as get to level x, cast spell y, done.  I was thinking of perhaps linking her to the Daelkyr in some way and maybe having him battle the ancient evil for the fate of his mother.  Something like that.  What are your thoughts, advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is there a system for modeling insanity in d20 3.5?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/11608)

Comment: I disagree with the flagging of this as a duplicate, for the same reason the person who unflagged it the first time had. I am grateful for the depth of the response from KRyan, it provided a more thorough answer than what was available in the thread that this supposedly duplicated.  Further it answered my question, where as the answers in that thread were tailored to the question asked there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Almost-nothing under the rules can withstand *miracle* or *wish*

These 9th-level spells are largely designed to be the end-all, be-all answers to problems, particularly curses and afflictions. *Wish* is slightly more powerful (and significantly more costly), so there are a few things *miracle* cannot do but *wish* can (e.g. permanently kill the tarrasque).

Both of the WotC-published sanity systems described in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/11620/4563) fall in this category: the *Unearthed Arcana* sanity variant has all insanity healed completely by *miracle* or *wish*, while the *Heroes of Horror* taint variant has *miracle* or *wish* remove large amounts of taint (and repeat castings can remove it entirely).

The [Lay Curse](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/divine/divineAbilitiesFeats.htm#layCurse) salient divine ability could make something that can only be removed by a deity, but Eberron deities are not active in the world in this fashion (excepting – maybe – the Silver Flame, but the Silver Flame would not<sup>1</sup> curse someone with madness). In particular, the daelkyr do not have salient divine abilities.

#### You are therefore going to have to rely on DM fiat to withstand *miracle* or *wish*

The various Eberron books describe this kind of pervasive madness, particularly as a result of daelkyr interference, all the time. But the specific mechanism for it is not described, because it is intended to just be done by DM fiat: you make the NPC insane, and make up what (if any) solutions to that insanity are available.

This is the approach the books recommend.

#### But worth considering: Eberron lacks much in the way of high-level magic

For all Eberron is a high-magic setting, it is more accurately described as a setting with ubiquitous-but-low-level magic. If an affliction requires *miracle* to cure, there are literally only one source in all of Khorvaire (Jaela Daran, the Keeper of the Flame, and then only while she is actually physically within the cathedral at Flamekeep). The *wish* spell is basically unavailble to mortals.

The *awakened* oak druid Oalian is capable of casting 9th-level spells, but as a druid does not receive either *miracle* or *wish*.

Some of the major organizations in Khorvaire might be able to put together the resources necessary to get a 9th-level spell like *miracle* or *wish* cast. Most of the dragonmarked houses could probably do it if they put their minds to it (though Phiarlan, Tharashk, Thuranni, and Vadalis probably not). So too the governments of Aundair, Breland, and Karrnath (since the Thranish head of state *is* the aforementioned Jaela Daran, they obviously can). But this is again DM fiat, allowing for some alternate form of casting high-level spells without any single spellcaster capable of doing it.

The only other sources are not people you want to be dealing with: the Lords of Dust, the daelkyr themselves, and the dragons of Argonessen. The last aren’t *all* bad, but even the “good” ones are very difficult to get the (positive) attention of.

So you’re looking at a situation where it is **very** difficult to get a hold of these powerful magics. In Eberron, player characters **don’t** simply attain 17th level and then go ahead and cast these spells. The *Heroes of Horror* taint rules make it impossible to get back above certain thresholds without the use of these spells, though the *Unearthed Arcana* sanity variant does allow ways to slowly restore sanity with lower level spells (even the 3rd-level *lesser restoration*).

Basically, I would not be so quick to dismiss ailments and implementations that allow *miracle* or *wish* to heal things; those spells are very, very difficult to come by in Eberron.

#### <sup>1</sup> Alternatively, maybe the Silver Flame *did* use Lay Curse

It’s kind of a stretch, but *Faiths of Eberron* describes a heretical cult within the Church of the Silver Flame that believes that the fiend bound by Tira Miron and the couatl remains active within the Flame. This so-called Shadow of the Flame is believed by some (labeled the Tarnished by the orthodoxy) to speak through the Voice in the Darkness, to manipulate the faithful and prey on the greed of the corruptible.

*Faiths of Eberron* explicitly states that the Shadow in the Flame does **not** have the power of a deity, and furthermore that much of its power is believed to be bound within the so-called Antikeeper, Melysse Miron. However, fudging this is an arguably smaller change than just fiating some kind of madness affliction, and this angle certainly does open up some exciting possibilities for plot hooks:

The Shadow in the Flame is not supposed to exist, much less exert this kind of power, and the one group that might have access to a cure (the Church itself) has an extremely strong vested interest in denying that this could have happened. The Diet of Cardinals definitely has factions within it, and not all of them are nice, even good: you could have some trying to suppress these claims, and keep the Keeper Jaela from hearing of it (and testing her *miracle* against the madness), for the “greater good,” while others might actively be “Tarnished” looking to further the goals of the Shadow.

Comment: Well said, KRyan.  I will review Unearthed Arcana this afternoon.  If it doesn't fit, then I will use DM fiat as you mentioned.

Comment: @GaryHarris Note the update. Also, it’s often desirable to *not* accept an answer, as others may skip a question that’s been “solved,” where they otherwise might have provided an even-better answer.

Comment: Thanks, KRyan.  Still pretty new to this format myself.  I have undone the accept for now.

Answer (score 5):

There's an old saying in D&D that roughly goes: If it has stats, the players will find a way to kill it. The take away being if you have something that you need as a fixture of your setting that can't be killed, don't give it stats. The Lady of Pain is a great example of this. Players HAVE to tread carefully around her, because no matter what loopholes they exploit they will never be able to harm her and she will always be able to harm them.

Given your constraints, a similar philosophy can be applied to madness. Rules are great if you want players interacting with a thing (e.g. falling into madness as the game progresses and being reliably able to cure it so it doesn't become a game clock). This is the exact opposite of what you want this instance of madness to do. You don't need rules for the descent, because the NPC is already mad and it doesn't sound like something that might also happen to the players. Similarly, you don't want a reliable way of curing it, because it would have already been used.

The solution is to make the cure a story point, just like any other major objective, rather than a question of applying the right rules. If you go this route, then what you need to do is first figure out why she's mad and then figure out what would fix it. (e.g. for the Daelkyr it's probably killing the Daelkyr, for the curse it's probably finding a macguffin). Then you can turn this into a series of quests or b-plots (depending on how significant you want it to be to the story). Generally, this can take 3 stages: Determine the nature of the madness, determine what cures the madness, act on the cure.

Comment: Lord British Postulate